# Erro ao Instalar Ionic + Cordova

Tags: node.js, ionic, npm, cordova-plugin

mensagens de erro quando tento instalar o Ionic (npm install -g cordova ionic)
alguém poderia me ajudar? estou usando o node 6.9. Obrigado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se estiver usando Linux ou Mac, coloca o sudo antes do npm install.

Comment: opa, não...é W10 :/

Comment: Estou com mesmo problema, tentei ontem e não consegui. Hoje a noite vou tentar desinstalar o Ionic e instalar novamente

Comment: Tente executar o cmd como administrador.

Comment: @JadsonMedeiros eu executei com adm tbm...desinstalei o node, reinstalei , mas acontece o mesmo problema...vou tentar no notebook para ver se dar o mesmo problema...

Comment: @AndréVicente eu fiz isso tbm

Comment: Tenta fazer esses passo aqui https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14003#issuecomment-249408972 . Eu fiz um parecido com esse, não encontrei onde foi que eu segui, mas era tipo isso

Comment: Abra o seu Internet Explorer e clique em Ferramentas > Opções Internet. Clique na aba Conexões e selecione Configurações da LAN. Ative a caixa Usar um servidor proxy para a LAN. No campo do Endereço, digite o endereço do servidor Proxy

Comment: Para instalar o Ionic e o Cordova, é recomendado a versão mais recente do node. Desinstale e reinstale-o para receber a versão atual. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Uma possível solução seria executar os seguintes passos:

```
1 - Instalar a ultima versao do NodeJS disponivel no site;
2 - Abrir o prompt de comando do NodeJS como administrador;
3 - Execute: npm cache clean;
4 - Execute: npm uninstall -g ionic
5 - Execute: npm uninstall -g cordova
6 - Execute: npm install -g ionic
7 - Execute: npm install -g cordova
```